# Error:dimension types not allowed(at 'button' with value)

Tags: xml, xamarin.android

i am writing an XML file with the following code:

```
<layer-list>
  <item android:right="5sp" android:top="5dp">
    <shape>
      <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
      <solid android:color="#D6D6D6"/>
    </shape>
  </item>

  <item android:button="2dp" android:left="2dp">
    <shape>
      <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#4A6EA9" android:startColor="#4A6EA9" />
      <stroke android:width ="1dp" android:color="#BABABA" />
      <corners android:radius="2dp" />
      <padding android:button="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10sp" android:top="10sp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

I can't figure out why I keep getting the errors:

Error:dimension types not allowed(at 'button' with value 10dp)

Error:dimension types not allowed(at 'button' with value 2dp)

I am also getting warning messages saying:

Error code: IDE0006: "Error Encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled."

"could not find schema information for the element 'corners'."

"could not find schema information for the element 'Gradient'."

"could not find schema information for the element 'item'."

"could not find schema information for the element 'schema'."

"could not find schema information for the element 'padding'."

"could not find schema information for the element 'selector'."

"could not find schema information for the element 'shape'."

"could not find schema information for the element 'size'."

"could not find schema information for the element 'solid'."

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... in my code i was typing in android:button... should be android:bottom...

don't know how i mislooked that... that fixed the error messages. I am still getting the IDE warning. Not sure how i can fix that. If i open up a new project I don't get the error in the new project.